# return a struct from a function to main.c?

Tags: c, function, struct, embedded, stm32

Hello I need ***RTC_TimeStruct*** and ***RTC_DateStruct*** from this function from hw_rtc.c file because these have time datas like second and minute or day. This function return ticks but i can not convert it to time and data. So, I decided to get this struct to my main file and read time.

```
 * @brief Get the RTC timer value
 * @param none
 * @retval RTC Timer value in ticks
 */
uint32_t HW_RTC_GetTimerValue( void )
{
  RTC_TimeTypeDef RTC_TimeStruct;
  RTC_DateTypeDef RTC_DateStruct;

  uint32_t CalendarValue = (uint32_t) HW_RTC_GetCalendarValue(&RTC_DateStruct, &RTC_TimeStruct );

  return (CalendarValue);

}
```

In my main file I tried something like this but unfortunately failed.

```
void rxDoneEventCallback(uint8_t *payload, uint16_t size, int16_t rssi, int8_t snr)
{
    //BSP_LED_On(LED2);

    TimerStart(&ledTimer);
    RTC_TimeTypeDef *tStruct = {0};
    tStruct = HW_RTC_GetTimerValue();

        if( (payload[0] + (payload[1]<<8)) > 4095 )  
            {

            garbageRxDataCount++ ;          
            }
        else
            {
                vcom_Send("Second: %d Minute: %d Data: %d"  ,tStruct->Seconds, tStruct->Minutes, payload[0] +  (payload[1]<<8));
                PRINTF("\n");
            }
}
```

Comment: If `HW_RTC_GetTimerValue` returns ticks, then you need to get that return as-is then, in your code, convert the ticks to minutes and seconds. You can't just return a `uint_32` into a struct. Even if you forced it in some way, it doesn't do the conversion you are after.

Comment: I can write a new function dont return a `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is call `HW_RTC_GetCalendarValue()` directly.

`HW_RTC_GetTimerValue()` is calling `HW_RTC_GetCalendarValue()` and discards the structured data.

```
  RTC_TimeTypeDef time ;
  RTC_DateTypeDef date ;

  HW_RTC_GetCalendarValue( &date , &time ) ;
```

`RTC_DateStruct` and `RTC_TimeStruct` will be filled with the date and time data by `HW_RTC_GetCalendarValue()`.

Comment: When I call it directly error appear that, "undefined reference to `"HW_RTC_GetCalendarValue()"`. It is a static function.

Comment: I have changed static function and i have done it like you said. Thank you very much.

Comment: I admit that my answer was intuitive - it is not clear whose API this is or where it is defined / documented - I guessed.  You should include that information in your question.  Whatever it is [this](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BNtPDe/getting-rtc-value) suggests that under the hood it uses `HAL_RTC_GetDate()`/`HAL_RTC_GetTime()` which you could use directly to avoid all the unnecessary calculation of "ticks" that you are then discarding.  You will however need to chack for consistency between date/time in case you read the date at midnight for example.

Comment: Yeah i know I should use that functions. Further i need microseconds, but for now I am working with this, miliseconds.

Comment: @fury : You need a very large integer to encode time/date in microseconds - or even milliseconds with any sufficiently long epoch.  It seems unlikely that you would want time/date in microsecond resolution.  For _relative_ microsecond timing you are better off using SYSCLK or a timer peripheral.  That is not really what RTCs are good for.

Comment: yes, i need more resolution, so i will look for SYSCLK after that. I am trying to add a timestamp to ADC data for reference to compare sensor datas which are transmit wirelessly. For know this resolution could be enough for progress.